# how to setup linux-igd to use webserver on same machine

Tags: linux, webserver, dhcp, tcpip, upnp

So I have a web server on port 80 and linux-igd/upnp running on the same machine using dhcp.  I want to configure linux-igd to be a way to get to the webserver.

I found this tag in the linux-igd xml files:

```
<presentationURL>http://myIp Adress</presentationURL>
```

I can set the ip address manually and remote systems can get to the servers web page just fine, but since we're using dhcp, it'll stop working once the address changes.

using

```
"http://localhost"
```

didn't work because the remote system would just try to connect to localhost on it's self.

What do I put in this xml tag for it to use its own dhcp ip address?

Answer (score 0):

You have four ways:

1. Use IP reservation on DHCP server;
2. Use static IP on this host;
3. Use DNS name instead of "myIp Adress";
4. Configure IP-DNSName in /etc/hosts file for all remote systems (will
   work only on these hosts).

Comment: I'm trying to let a user use a windows pc without installing anything and connect it our linux system's web server without using a static ip address or configuring their router.  Other linux systems can use mdns to connect to our system via hostname, but I can't require users to install apple bonjour print services.  So i'm trying to implement upnp solution for the windows users.